# Terminal in Geany

Tags: 12.04, command-line, geany

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04, I am a big fan of Geany, but now i don't have the terminal at the base of the window. I have tried to change the terminal preferences, without success. any ideas?

Comment: You need to install libvte -- but you don't need to install libvte-dev. This is only needed for compiling purpose.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is because Ubuntu12 lacks `libvte.so`, or at least the version Geany uses to emulate the terminal. Try this command

```
sudo apt-get install libvte-dev
```

Comment: Only libvte9 is required.... the -dev installs a lot of unneeded things.

Comment: -dev is really seriously overkill.

Answer (score 11):

You can only install to enable the terminal tab: libvte9

Comment: This is basically saying the same thing as the accepted answer above, right?

Comment: Thanks, that helped me. In my installation (ubuntu 12.04) I had `libvte-2.90-9` already installed and because of some problem I was't able to install `libvte-dev`.

Answer (score 8):

Geany uses GTK+ 2.0 so you need libvte9

```
sudo apt-get install libvte9
```

Comment: This is the answer, no need to install libvte-dev which installs 90MB of packages.

Answer (score 1):

Did You try to enable Menu-> View -> Show Message Window ? This will enable Geany bottom panel, where on left You will have "Terminal" tab ( the last one ).

Comment: Yes the message window is visable, but does not have a terminal tab. as seen here --> http://goo.gl/41Ihu