# Gedit embedded terminal is empty

Tags: 12.04, gedit

I enabled the Embedded terminal plug-in for gedit, but it only appears as in the picture. I can't type anything!

[image]

Is there a way to fix this? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I have same problem did you find a solution? Or is there another editor with terminal?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I now use Geany as a text editor and for coding and all that. It has a terminal, and works pretty well.

Comment: I had similar problem with geany, but it was easier to fix (http://askubuntu.com/questions/139539/terminal-in-geany/203165#comment293672_203165).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem before. The problem turns out to be the color of the words in this embedded terminal is white, so you can't see them. Follow this link[Make gedit embedded terminal colours the same as the default terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67593/make-gedit-embedded-terminal-colours-the-same-as-the-default-terminal), you could change the color to be normal black.