# Geany Terminal window

Tags: command-line, geany

I would like to know if there is a way we can display the "Terminal Window" permanently on the right side or in bottom in Geany. I have tried checking all the menu items but couldnt find out how to actually do it.

I am very new to ubuntu your guidance in this regard will be of great help.

Answer (score 3):

You should just need to make sure the check mark is against 'Show Message Window' in the View menu:

[image]

However, even if you have this selected you might not see the message window at the bottom of the screen and may need to pull it up with the mouse. After that you should see this at the bottom of the Geany main screen:

[image]

If you still can't get the desired result, also check menu > edit > preferences > interface and look at the options there regarding the 'Message window', not the sidebar. You can choose between showing the 'Message window', which includes the terminal window, at the bottom or on the right:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure you see the message window using advice on this page.
2. If the terminal tab is missing from the message window, then follow advice [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139539/terminal-in-geany#139562)

Note: I used the recommended command: `sudo apt-get install libvte-dev`, which other users on that page suggest is overkill and offer different versions.