# shortcut to send selection to terminal in geany

Tags: 14.04, command-line, shortcuts, geany

So i've [set up the geany to use with the terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139539/terminal-in-geany). My next question is how to set up a keyboard shortcut to send the currently selected code to the terminal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default there's no such shortcut defined but you can easily assign a new one.

Open the **Edit** -> **Preferences** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>) menu and click on the **Keybindings** tab:

[image]

Scroll down into the "Format" category to find and select a "Send Selection to Terminal" action. Click the <kbd>Change</kbd> button to assign a new shortcut and you can now send your selection to the VTE Terminal:

[image]

Comment: where can I get terminal output?

Comment: @hellboy I've updated my answer. The terminal is the one embedded in Geany (VTE)

Comment: And Terminal is configurable  in [Tools preferneces](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/#tools-preferences) ?

Comment: Is Geany the simplest/the only way to do subj ?

Comment: @hellboy http://askubuntu.com/questions/139539/terminal-in-geany may answer your question