# Geany: *execute* line in Terminal

Tags: geany

I have a problem with Geany. I [can](https://askubuntu.com/q/528367/2413) set a keyboard shortcut to *send* selection to the terminal. But these line are just copied on the terminal, not executed. So, if you select this line:

```
R
```

and send it to the terminal, `R` is not actually executed, instead the letter `R` appears in the terminal prompt. If I press "enter" then `R` is launched. How can I make that last "enter" be automatically send to the terminal together with the selection?

Is there a keyboard shortcut to send *and execute* the selection in the terminal?

Comment: No, as with 1.27 there isn't. You could define a shell script which is executing what it's receiving as via STDIN and configure it for the send selection to feature.

Comment: @frlan: is this solution easy to do; could you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing `send_selection_unsafe=false` to `send_selection_unsafe=true` in the `geany.conf` file (`~/.config/geany/geany.conf`) fixed this for me.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with geany so I could be wrong here but you probably need to add CrLf to the end of the line. Most programs this can be specified with \r\n maybe that will help.

Comment: \r is an escape sequence that represents the carriage return character \n represents a new line character also called line feed, both are used due to historical typewriters where they were two separate operations.