# Geany output in terminal

Tags: command-line, python, geany

When I press the run button on Geany with Python 3.5, I get the outputs in a new terminal window.

I guess that it should be linked with Preferences>Tools>Terminal where I have written `xterm -e "/bin/sh %c"` (following the [Geany manual](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#tools-preferences)).

Is there a way to see the Python code output in the Message Window ?

Answer (score 4):

Following [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139539/terminal-in-geany?rq=1) I finally installed libvte9 with command `sudo apt-get install libvte9`

It works with the precious needed settings:

- Preferences>Terminal>Shell: `/bin/sh`
- Preferences>Terminal: check "Execute programs in the VTE"