# How to change default terminal of Geany to Konsole (or another emulator that supports CTL)?

Tags: command-line, language-support, geany

I am using [Konsole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konsole) as a terminal to contribute to wikimedia pages. I use Konsole because unlike most terminal emulators it supports CTL (complex text layout) so I can clearly read my language (Tamil) in Konsole. The default terminal of Geany is not so good. I want to change the default terminal. How can I do that?

Comment: What version of Geany do you have?

Comment: 1.27 (Rezer-built on or after 2016-04-17)

Comment: Does any terminal appear in Geany? I have the same version but only see Status, Compiler, Messages, and Scribble. No terminal at all.

Comment: [See settings.](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Geany#/media/File:Geany_0.10_de.png). Check here. Edit-->Preferences-->manyTabs-->Terminal

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see a terminal tab. I hope someone can help you! You could also sign up at https://lists.geany.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/users where Geany devs are available.

Answer (score 5):

#### Way 1: You can change the terminal in the *Tools* tab in Geany's preferences.

In its Edit → Preferences dialog, Geany has a Tools tab. (This is separate from the Terminal tab.) One of the utility selections that you can configure from the Tools tab is *Terminal*.

[image: screenshot showing Terminal selection in the Tools tab of the Preferences dialog in Geany]

It has this as its default value, but you can change it to whatever you like:

```
x-terminal-emulator -e "/bin/sh %c"
```

So one way to make it use Konsole instead of whatever `x-terminal-emulator` is configured to run is to replace `x-terminal-emulator` with `konsole`. (Don't capitalize the `k`.) That is, one solution is to change that command to this one:

```
konsole -e "/bin/sh %c"
```

Geany itself substitutes for `%c` when it actually launches a terminal emulator. Whatever terminal emulator it calls *does* have to support a `-e` flag--or you can change that commmand accordingly if it doesn't. (Specifically what to write instead would depend on whatever syntax it *did* accept.) But most terminals do, and [this includes Konsole](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43726632#43726632).

#### Way 2: You can change what program `x-terminal-emulator` points to.

As an alternative solution that you might prefer, if you pretty much always want Konsole in *any* context where a terminal is opened, then you might want to just reconfigure `x-terminal-emulator` to launch Konsole instead of whatever other terminal it is currently launching.

If you choose to do this, then I recommend still checking in the Preferences dialog in Geany to make sure that it *is* actually using that `x-terminal-emulator` command shown above.

In Debian and Ubuntu, the `x-terminal-emulator` [symlink](http://foldoc.org/symbolic+link) is managed by [the alternatives system](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives). To adjust it so that it points to a different terminal command, [you can run](https://askubuntu.com/a/124718/22949):

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

You will be prompted to select one of the terminal emulators that is currently installed. Assuming Konsole is installed on your system, you should be able to select `/usr/bin/konsole`.

#### Acknowledgements

**[Zanna](https://askubuntu.com/users/527764/zanna) contributed [substantially](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43726489#43726489) toward this answer.**

See also the [Geany manual](https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#tools-preferences) (linked from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852611/geany-output-in-terminal), though that is *not* asking for the same thing, as the VTE is Geany's built-in terminal, which it sounds like you do *not* want to use).

Comment: Also, In Geany 1.36 Poliff, on debian+XFCE change to `xfce4-terminla` works